# Typescript - variable number of generic types in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have a component "ListItemComponent" that I can use like that :

```typescript
const user: User = { id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" };
const address: Address = { id: 2, city: "Lurenberg", country: "Listenbourg" };
const rdv: Rdv = { id: 3, date: "today" };
const other: Other = { id: 3, lambda: "lorem ipsum" };

// the main "obj" is type of "User"
// some items can define their own "obj" (Rdv, Address, Other...)
<ListItemComponent
  obj={user}
  items={[
    { field: "firstname" },
    { field: "lastnam" }, // !! OK ts error !! (field does not exist in object "user")
    { obj: address, itemKey: "addrCity", field: "city" },
    { obj: address, itemKey: "addrCity2", field: "cityyyy" }, // !! OK ts error !! (field does not exist in object "address")
    { obj: address, field: "country" }, // !! OK ts error !! (missing itemKey)

    // !! NOK !! (I should be able to use other type of AbstracObj (rdv, other...)
    { obj: rdv, itemKey: "rdvDate", field: "date" },

    // !! NOK !! (should be an error because "lambdaaaa" does not exist in object "other", its "lambda")
    { obj: other, itemKey: "other", field: "lambdaaaa" },
  ]}
/>


// with component looking something like :
const ListItemComponent = <T extends AbstractObj, T2 extends AbstractObj>(
  props: ListItem<T, T2>
) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map((item) => {
        const obj = (item as any).obj ?? props.obj;
        const field = item.field as FieldT<typeof obj>;
        const value = obj[field];
        const key = ((item as any)?.itemKey ?? item.field) as Key;

        return <li key={key}>
          <>{field} : {value ?? "!! field does not exist !!"}</>
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

The rules are :

- ListItemComponent has a main "obj" of type T
- If an item does NOT defined its own property "obj", then it will be of type "ItemBase" and its "field" must be a keyof T
- If item DOES defined "obj", it also had to define the property "itemKey" and its "field" will be a keyof T2 (type of its own "obj")
- Different items can have different "obj" types (T2, T3, ... but all extending AbstractObj)

The different types that I have defined to do that :

```typescript
// ListItemComponent props :
export interface ListItem<T extends AbstractObj, T2 extends AbstractObj> {
  obj: T; // it MUST have a main "obj"
  items: (ItemBase<T> | ItemWithObj<T2>)[]; // array whose items can be either ItemBase or ItemWithObj
  //items: XOR<ItemBase<T>, ItemWithObj<T2>>[]; // also try with an exclusive OR
}

// An item of type T has a field that must be a keyof T and an optional change function that also depend on the T type
export interface ItemBase<T extends AbstractObj> {
  field: FieldT<T>;
}

// Item that defined "obj" : it extends ItemBase, so the property "field" must be keyof "obj" type
export interface ItemWithObj<T extends AbstractObj> extends ItemBase<T> {
  obj: T;
  itemKey: string;
}

// All T types must extend AbstractObj
export interface AbstractObj {
  id: number;
}

// Helper types
export type FieldT<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type Without<U1, U2> = { [P in Exclude<keyof U1, keyof U2>]?: never };
type XOR<U1, U2> = U1 | U2 extends object
  ? (Without<U1, U2> & U2) | (Without<U2, U1> & U1)
  : U1 | U2;


// Exemple of some Objects interface that can be used
interface User extends AbstractObj {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}
interface Address extends AbstractObj {
  city: string;
  country: string;
}
interface Rdv extends AbstractObj {
  date: string;
}
interface Other extends AbstractObj {
  lambda: string;
}
```

[Here's all of that together in a Codesandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-typescript-generic-types-question-jb8550?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx).

[Or in a Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=4&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgBlgBnGASRiRAGFdIA7JXvDA4wjOAC5ySAB6RYcYIKRRM6JPSat2IADwAVODPa8AJmICCAI2ZR0MAPKWAVgBo4egEyHpxs3Cs2do5OAHxwAN7kcHAQzuLupHA0CvAAsgCqAMoGABYoAG7qKHAgKIoEsU74USkcjPEAFGwcAEIojEj6YQA+cM0gAOrAMDnB+h4hAJQA2gC6ickoULYAnnAA7jkQHbUgYmgovHCW6kjDOcp92m070FccQyPBNTTDdfEAGvYIOv03nXoQm5+o9Rs5xiEQnMFrQlqsNlsdm89nADkcToZzpc-u11HcQedngBfSjJcxHZExTBwGArMDqXLtODFTDAJAAGxMNLy8BAAFdmMcinAANZIFYQakGQ5cw4xMAwYAQXgodmovK8ADm6kwfN4GCVRxGKHgqsYEDgJiQ9NMMSNF3cNLpSCksmg8EU7BUanuIH++m8vgs1hgtgwwTCkWirI5JniADE2Zy9F0KCTqLR+tyTZakKz+Fz8JV8BIUoGBH4cR03ObuephBB6bA1vgY5yS-zBRixRLqUXnCXafTXXIPUpvWh1ASnuCDEYK8HAuHnGF56YxFWAZGapV4noKNFkQBpcXxGyKTVp0m0czstUGIdIMSd+BrrkBUNBZwj90KceqSd-BDMMHGcCIamAOM4F4PkQBOKArwzOAAAkOSbJ16UYH95EfOBE1jFNATgABeOAAFEfBAnQe0ldwa1DC8QgoXDQQgPkYB0dIAEY3HSCYSIiOBpgABT-cjpDQdk+StajxVo7i3Bo6k+JCWYAH54n4QooDgIlmOdOAvh+BS4BUgTuLgXo+PLdcYmcJAMBqNS4AaVj2M4njTP4gAyLzJksly3I4vjeK4sJfO4yYaniCyrI8Chrw2c5UR4ZUBHgdkIAgEULzgc0QCQEZcvZYAxQkcg0GVQUGGYfpuHANLBAEgM30XT9l1cdwvFaoCl1A0IGhqBtRHiGqtA4fQ3E8EJyH84jt2iIgYD5KAjkG6Joh0Pl2RmjaNvCYbGAAOmRY7SjABoGmROaFr2jbKt4QVKgEq7tGZMRDhWSYjuetTnMOn7nAPO7ogewU2y5UjkSOiH3rwpMTBTR9aMqJiahBsH4HyVU+XUUjKmmCH5nRu7MdFcUXtejg4c+yY1JO7QTzWP7dhhhH-KZZA7COpmEpBxbCpWo4dBK8mVmI8IeyJXb+c2kJwgholS3CbGpPUFn8AAQk1uBYZMCAn2giBX2kTQ4G1-AiR0KgZZB62SttjaiUmEk9ut7aZcmNMEqQiiODAdk8WpfL1GCByYDET1lAA9RjXgNEhTgAUkBMcgo4ndR0g6HSeo-EDgnA6NgCgZgVQKs8GK1YH2XaGAy6QCuoAvK905j-wTBMIhGDEXPgK-JxC9RYYVkb5uakqvVQxHvLK8vcgSVbn0EBMfIbL8PP+8HkwTQbmem6r+e0--H17BGS5e76guozgGu4O30eD-TXV9UVZV-DAC7-Ovsnk6gGLs4EuEBQUFPKshLnXFA5cCAACkIA5F4PgNwNdS6QN3vgAAIgbEselx5VVNB3Lu9R26dyfGIUiQDILxA8G4NAw94j4DoCtAQ8FNSIJSpPKA08GGaGYWxKArDdLAzJlAFe8Rl6r3IcA+IABmNw292D0JgBAbeKxsFCLwTEM+f84CnwuDpSRlC4CyJvpAyw98CCZSIHgYAohYJqMoNEZIZ8ShlCOP2KoCgxC4VovgLOyhqiONoCHXY+w5RWnzLHC4xcYjrDccWFy4i3DmAIaQtwujlBHUyVFAWy1VouRJjoMadVUr8EECTaIlQJa-1dndU6EtpjlP2rrBG9CwEoIKtglwjTohAIhvQ5BECQCdKSLQbWOijw0h7ssO4YyGh6wNmIXgxtvBm3KJUcOBBf74GyfzIBu5mQpO7m4Y8p4CAoAIZwYebC+kEFobSTp3TBL7POSQo5uwmb0JeVAS5tIPDXJabc4eKxgXDOSGM+wEyI6GGmTpWZ8zDZLJNqso46yMBnMOYwbZjy9lxAOa8xgbgbn4AnoIThoLRk6whZM6FOBYU6waCAJgjBconK+g4-mYKdYADkqWzJYHlLY20uQYhQJYQONILTJ00XojCQdertQLg0ER+Q3DGz0Zko6OyQY4qcPEZVxzGanMICvdBO9-mxnofIpADzHmcrgDyiZszGCCs5InOUyhaVCgOFK-At8zEoADSgEs+sEXLJkMiuyTgNlFi0Ww4YYhfWmO3li2WOr4hquUAajgHyKixsJQCxNd9A1Bt0l0kGswamOM9mmIAA).

I manage to have a nice type inference with two different AbstractObj types (e.g. - the main "obj" of type "User", and a secondary one of type "Address")

My question is :

*How can I do to allow more than one type of secondary "obj" (e.g. - rdv, other...)... and still have this typescript validation on "field" ? (cf. !! NOK comments !!)*

Comment: Is this really a *minimal* [mre]?  Is there any way you could remove the parts of it that are not causing trouble for you? This is almost certainly something you should approach with mapped tuple types, but I'm not inclined to go wading through the `XOR<ItemBase<T>, ItemWithObj<T2>>` stuff just to get there.

Comment: It is hard to remove code from the TS playground mention in the post :/ 
My problem comes precisely from the fact that I want to use more than 2 different types of "obj", and when I do, I still want to have those error if I use wrong 'field' names.
I mean that the first 3 errors, I want to have them  (because I made a typo error) ! But the 2 lasts are errors due to the fact I use other types of objects, not because of typo error in the field name... and that is what I want to fix !

Comment: I understand that you need `T2[]` to work more like `[T2, T3, T4, ⋯, TN]`; that's fine.  The complicated part is that you're doing some weird conditional type with `XOR`, and it doesn't seem like you're asking about that in particular.  With the example as written I tried some things but nothing worked particularly well and I'm not inclined to spend much more time on it unless it gets simplified to something more direct (again, the part to simplify is not the `T2, T3, T4⋯` part, but the `XOR<ItemBase<T>, ItemWithObj<T?>>` part). Maybe someone else can help with the code as-is, though!

Comment: Oh okay sorry I understand ! So initially, I was doing a simple OR : 
`items: (ItemBase<T> | ItemWithObj<T2>)[]`

...and I was having an issue with that but to be honest I cannot reproduce again in this simplified playground... so let me update the post with that !

(of what I remember, the issue was that the code was allowing me to add a weird mix of ItemBase and ItemWithObj in a single item)

Comment: **Yuck.** Getting inference to work here was really tough, and I had to resort to a lot of obnoxious tricks that are essentially impenetrable.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYLPvm) is what it looks like.  If that works for you, I *might* write up an answer explaining, but... well, yuck.  Not sure how to move forward here.

Comment: **yuck** indeed, but also **Whooo !!**  
I am still trying to understand how it works exactly, but that is what I was looking for... thanks a lot !

Comment: So do you want me to write up an answer?  I can give a broad overview of how it works, but some of it is so fiddly that I would probably write ten pages of detail and it would still probably be confusing.

Comment: If it doesn't bother you, that would be awesome!